# How can I access the waveform played by my speakers?

Tags: audio, language-agnostic, project

I am looking to start a project that alters the waveform being fed into your speakers by analyzing the waveform that comes out. I know that MATLAB has some pretty nice tools for altering the waveform being played by your speakers, but I would really prefer to use a nicer more efficient language. What would be the best language/package for the purposes of this project? Ideally I would like to be able to simply add waves into something already being played by the speaker. Suggestions?

Comment: Answer will be platform-dependent so you will need to specify OS etc

Comment: I am currently looking for an application on windows, but I would want to know for the answer on any OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cross-platform, you could try using the [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) library, and C as the most common language for real-time DSP code.

You could capture sound from speakers by plugging the line-out or a mic in front of the speakers into a USB ADC.